# Does Yorick's passive count towards his ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Yorick's ultimate "Omen of Death" count as one more summon from his passive or not? Quote from passive:" Yorick takes 5% less damage and his autoattacks deal 5% more damage for each **summon** that is active."

Answer (score 5):

Yes, having his ultimate summon active also increases Yorick's damage and damage reduction.
From the [League of Legends wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Yorick_the_Gravedigger/Ability_Details):

> Unholy Covenant is a passive ability, causing Yorick to deal more
>   damage with his autoattacks and reduce incoming damage by a
>   percentage. The strength of this effect is determined by the number of
>   summoned units from Yorick's champion abilities that are currently
>   active.
>
> Summoned units include the  Spectral Ghoul,  Decaying Ghoul, 
>   Ravenous Ghoul and  Revenant.